# updating inactive form.text from a thread in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to update form.text from a thread. Basically thread need to update the form.text with the current time. my code looks like below

```
UpdateText("My Monitor (Last Updated " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + ")", Form1.ActiveForm);
```

and the method as below

```
    void UpdateText(String s, Control c)
    {
        if (c.InvokeRequired)
        {

            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateText(s, c)));

        }
        else
        {
            c.Text = s;
        }
    }
```

As long as the main application window is active, code works. If the application becomes inactive, then I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: You could try simplifying things with a timer on each page

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Form1.ActiveForm`.

> [ActiveForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx): A Form that represents the currently active form, or null if there is no active form.

If the `Form` is inactive, naturally this would be `null`. Use a different reference to your form. If you are calling it from within the form, use `this`.

Comment: or when you run the thread you can pass in the instance of the form you want to update

Answer (score 0):

Keep the reference of `ActiveForm` in a private field, and use that field in the `Thread`

```
Control activeControl;
private void start_new_thread()
{
    active = Form1.ActiveForm;
    // start work under thread
}

private void work_under_thread(object state)
{

    //blocking works
    // update here
    UpdateText("My Monitor (Last Updated " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + ")", activeControl);

}
```